# Cannot call DecisionTreeClassifier.train()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, time-series, decision-tree

I am trying to use DecisionTreeClassifier.train() but it comes out to such error report:

> Error:(218, 41) method train in class DecisionTreeClassifier cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier
>    Access to protected method train not permitted because
>    enclosing object FeatureSelection in package core is not a subclass of 
>    class DecisionTreeClassifier in package classification where target is defined
>   val dt = decisionTreeClassifier.train(trainRdd)

It reports that my object `FeatureSelection` is not a subclass of package classification so it's unable to call a potected method of the package.But actually train() is a function with public type in official documents.

Surroundings: Scala 2.10.6 Spark 2.10:1.6.1 jdk 1.8

Here are the codes attached:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier

object FeatureSelection {
  def selectFeatureGreedyDTNoLimit(){
    val selectfeature=ArrayBuffer[String]()
    val selectsize=selectfeature.size
    val tempfeature=selectfeature++ArrayBuffer(line)

    val vectorDF = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(tempfeature.toArray)
      .setOutputCol("features")
      .transform(tempdf)
      .select("label", "features")

    val Array(trainRdd, testRdd) =
      vectorDF
      .rdd
      .map(row =>  LabeledPoint(Common.any2Double(row.get(0)).get, row.getAs[Vector](1)))
      .randomSplit(Array(0.5, 0.5), 0L)

    val numClasses = 2
    val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()

    val dt = decisionTreeClassifier.train(trainRdd, categoricalFeaturesInfo, numClasses)
  }
}
```

Hoping for someone to help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to use the method `fit`.

`train` is an internal function, that is why it is protected.